# Android sending packetets int8 to tcp server

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, sfml, packet

How can I send packet from android to SFML tcp server which is awaiting for int8 variable.

Server side:

```
  sf:Int8 liczbunia;
    listener.listen(55555);
    listener.accept(socket);
    cout << "connected";
    sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(500));
    socket.receive( paket );
    paket >>  liczba;
```

I tried this code for client side:

```
        Socket socketClient = new Socket("192.168.0.100",55555); 
        PrintWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream(),true);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
        dout.writeInt(9);
        dout.flush();
```

Although the client connects to server,  server doesn't receive the packet.
What is the best way to send packets from android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the tutorial on `sf::Packet`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/network-packet.php):

> Packets solve the "message boundaries" problem, which means that when you send a packet on a TCP socket, you receive the exact same packet on the other end, it cannot contain less bytes, or bytes from the next packet that you send. However, it has a slight drawback: To preserve message boundaries, sf::Packet has to send some extra bytes along with your data, which implies that you can only receive them with a sf::Packet if you want them to be properly decoded. **Simply put, you can't send an SFML packet to a non-SFML packet recipient, it has to use an SFML packet for receiving too.** Note that this applies to TCP only, UDP is fine since the protocol itself preserves message boundaries.

Solution: read raw data from the socket.